# How to properly setup "sensor" for collider for the React project which is using react-three-fiber and react-three-rapier?

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

Problem:
I created several mesh, and I want to detect for the new pending mesh, if it is intersected with other existing mesh, note that the "pending mesh" is moving with the mouse (the yellow square is the "pending mesh").
[pending mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jwf3.png)

So far, I already used the **three-react-rapier Rigibody**, **Collider** and **sensor** to detect if a shape is intersected with others by "**onIntersectionEnter**" and "**onIntersectionExit**" (reference: *https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-rapier#automatic-colliders*). When the "pending mesh" is intersected with the another mesh, the color of it changes from yellow to red.
[pending mesh is intersected with another existing mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OTOz.png)

However, I met an issue that, when the "pending mesh" is intersected with one existing mesh (that turns red, good), and if I keep moving the "pending mesh" toward to another existing mesh, which the "pending mesh" is intersected with both mesh now, and then, if I keep moving it to the left (another mesh), now the "pending mesh" left/quit the first mesh, at the same time, for some reason, the collider sensor/detection is also gone, it won't detect that the "pending mesh" actually is still intersected with the new mesh (the left one).
[pending mesh is intersected with 2 mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZzVa.png)
[pending mesh is intersected with another mesh, but not showing intersected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhEnz.png)

Therefore, I want to know if there is a way that I can solve this situation?
Thank you advance for your help :)

I tried to add <Rigibody /> and <Collider /> to each <mesh />, didn't work.

I attached my example code below, please take a look:

Code of "Pending mesh"

```
<>
    <CuboidCollider
        sensor
        position={[xCoord, 0, zCoord]}
        args={[pendingModel.length / 2, pendingModel.height, pendingModel.width / 2]}
        onIntersectionEnter={() => isIntersected(true)}
        onIntersectionExit={() => isIntersected(false)}
    />
    <mesh position={[xCoord, 0, zCoord]}>
        <boxGeometry
            attach="geometry"
            args={[pendingModel.length, pendingModel.height, pendingModel.width]} 
        />
            <meshLambertMaterial attach="material" color={intersected ? "red" : "orange"} />
    </mesh>
</>
```

xCoord, zCoord is where the mouse at on the scene, so that it gets passed to the pending mesh, so the pending mesh is always with the mosue.

Code of the existing mesh:

```
<RigidBody sensor>
    <mesh
        key={model.id}
        position={[model.positionX, model.positionY, model.positionZ]}
      >
        <boxGeometry attach="geometry" 
            args={[model.shapeLength, model.shapeHeight, model.shapeWidth]} />
        <meshLambertMaterial attach="material" color={model.shapeColor} />
    </mesh>
</RigidBody>
```